# Rendered fields manually from modelform..How can i save it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I am beginner in django.
I Rendered fields manually from modelform by using {{form.field_name}}.There are 5 fields in my model . how can i save field data by using class based view.

When Rendered fields by using {% form %} then i can save my form by using CreateView.like this

```
class StudentCreate(CreateView):
    model = StudentDetails
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list-student')
```

but when i Rendered fields manually from modelform by using {{form.field_name}}.. i can't save it by using Createview.. Any idea about it? Why is this not working ? How can i save it?

Forms.py

```
class Student(forms.ModelForm): 
class Meta:
    model = StudentDetails
    fields = "__all__"
```

Template code

{{form.name.label_tag}}
{{form.name}}

Comment: Post your forms.py and html part of the form

Comment: Rendering fields manually normally does not matter, so likely there is something wrong with the way you render the fields in the template. Can you share the part of the template where you render the form.

Comment: when rendering fields per hand make SURE you got everything right. Forgot the name attr in the input = not working. What I suggest is inspect element a django rendered form (one that was rendered using the {{form}} tag) and copy the format exactly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to be very careful and specific when naming your custom fields. If you don't, Django will not recognize the form fields and ignore them.

If you want to see how you should do it, just render your `{% form %}` and look in the source code. Then you have to use **exactly** same names for your custom fields.